Parse "12:00 a.m." as TimeOnly
I'm struggling with parsing strings ongoing in the "12:00 a.m." format.
I tried TimeOnly.TryParse("12:00 a.m.", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var result), but it doesn't work.
I looked through DateTimeStyles, but they aren't relevant.
The documentation doesn't look useful and this is something hard to google.
I found a library ChronicNetCore, but it looks like overkill here.
I am not sure that strings always will be like "12:00 a.m.", I think they can come as
"12:00AM" or "12:00 am" or "12 a.m.".
Isn't there any internal .Net solution for stable parsing American-culture-only "TimeOnly" strings?

If you want american format then don't use InvariantCulture but en-us as CultureInfo. But you presumably need to remove the dots in the AM/PM designator also. Casing/Whitespace between time and designator should be handled already.

Eventually, I've used an array of formats and two calls of TryParseExact, the later one with a custom format provider:
private bool TryParseTimeOnly(ReadOnlySpan<char> input, out TimeOnly value)
{
    string[] formats = [
        "h:mm tt",
        "hh:mm tt",
        "h tt",
        "h:mmtt",
        "hh:mmtt",
        "htt",
    ];

    if (TimeOnly.TryParseExact(
        input,
        formats,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out value))
    {
        return true;
    }

    var formatInfo = (DateTimeFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.Clone();
    formatInfo.AMDesignator = "a.m.";
    formatInfo.PMDesignator = "p.m.";
   
    if (TimeOnly.TryParseExact(
        input,
        formats,
        formatInfo,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out value))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

based on How to parse "string" to "DateTime" with "a. m." or "p. m." format (not AM/PM)? from @dbc

You can use TimeOnly.TryParseExact Method.
This documentation page shows an example very similar to yours (with ParseExact but you can apply similarly to TryParseExact):
var theTime = TimeOnly.ParseExact("5:00 pm", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  // Custom format

You can modify the format string according to your needs.
